# My button isn't square even when using: layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" in Kotlin, android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-button

I am trying to make an app using *constraintlayout* and guidelines. All works fine except when I'm trying to put a button.

Here is a screenshot of the design to show what the problem is: my button has a `layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` but it's not a square

[image: Button_Image]

my code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_settings_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_vertical2_home"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_vertical1_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal1_home" />
```

Where is the problem ? I've tried `padding="0dp"` and it didn't worked of course. I also tried to change the guidelines around it to see if that was the problem but it wasn't... So I tried looking on forums but I found nothing.

As you can see android studio make a square around the button, so I think that's just the button not taking all the place on the top and the bottom but I don't know how to fix it, if someone can help me that would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Don't specify either end or bottom constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual `Button` (the `View` itself) is square like you noticed, it's just the *background* being drawn (with the button's shape) has some vertical padding, and that's much more noticeable at small sizes (where the fixed padding is a larger proportion of the View's height).

You can adjust this with the `insetTop` and `insetBottom` properties:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_settings_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

which gives you.

[image: A visually square button with no padding, constrained by the guidelines]

These properties aren't auto-suggested, I'm guessing because you're not really meant to specify them on a View like this, but as part of a *style* you apply to it. I learned it from this [Material Design theming section](https://m2.material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button) where it shows you how to create a square button, icon-only style. So it *might* be better to create your own square style (inheriting from the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` one and just specifying the insets) and use that style on any of your buttons that need to be square.

(Or the Material3 equivalent if you're using that, since it's released as the current version now)